# 301 redirect all assets from http to https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, config, http-status-code-301

I've searched and tried but I can't seem to find an answer on how to 301 redirect all assets when moving my http site to full https.

I'm looking for a way to either use .htaccess or httpd.conf to 301 redirect all assets (images, pdf, videos, js, css, .txt, etc) from http to https.

The full structure of both http and https remain the same.

I would appreciate any guidance on this topic.

Thanks
William

Answer (score 0):

```
# Checking if HTTPS is enabled for current page   
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on 
# Redirecting any non-HTTPS document by this URL to HTTPS URL
RewriteRule (.*)\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js|pdf))$  https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1.$2 [R=301,L]
```

Taken from here: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS

Comment: Would that work on assets? I'm sure that would work on pages. I have this so far but not sur ehow to redirect to https from http. `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]*/)*([^/.]+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js|pdf))$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]`

Comment: It should work on any requested URL. I'll correct rules for yours extensions.

Comment: And `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` means that file shouldn't exist on requested URL, you should throw away this line.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I got it to work with the following: `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]*/)*([^/.]+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js|pdf))$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: Is there a way to do this in the httpd.conf file? I like to keep these redirects away from htaccess.

Comment: @William sure, you can specify them within `VirtualHost` directive. But your rule is little bit strange. Are you sure it works properly?

Comment: It does - It might be because I'm 301 redirecting all `http://`, `http://www`, `https://` to `https://www` via the .conf file.

Comment: I basically have `Redirect permanent / https://www.domain.com/` in servername www and nowww port 80, and nonwww in port 443. What would be written for these assets?

Comment: They're still redirecting. You have nothing to change to make them work.